# error: 1318 Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE | Flask

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, flask

I am getting this error message. It only works when **`_query`** has single character. Other wise throws and error message. I am using **MySQL extension** for **Flask**.

> {
>   error: "(1318, 'Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE alexspider.SearchStore; expected 1, got 2')"
>   }

**MySQL Procedure:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchStore(
 IN Keyword VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
 SELECT * 
 FROM noones
 WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', Keyword, '%');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

**Flask app.py**

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    try:
        # Read the posted values from the UI
        _query = request.form['query']

        # Validationg the search Quoey
        if _query:
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.callproc('SearchStore', _query)
            stores = cursor.fetchall()
            if len(stores) > 0:
                stores_dict = []
                for store in stores:
                    store_dict  ={
                    'name': store[2],
                    'url': store[3],
                    'cashback': store[4]}
                    stores_dict.append(store_dict)
                return json.dumps(stores_dict)
            else:
                return render_template('error.hml', error = 'This is error message')

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error': str(e)})
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: what is your procedure calling statement??

Comment: `cursor.callproc('SearchStore', _query)`

Comment: its clearly showing that you are passing 2 parameter in your procedure while your procedure have only 1 input argument type

Comment: What's the solution, i'm not getting

Comment: simple solution only pass one parameter like this cursor.callproc('SearchStore, _query')

Comment: That doesn't work. `callproc` is a method and `SearchStore` is a MySQLProcedure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111738/discussion-between-ganesh-pandey-and-jordan).

Comment: My question could be silly and I have no knowledge on MySQL but is it right to use `keyword1` inside the SQL procedure instead of the IN parameter (which is just `keyword` )??

Comment: Sorry that was a typo mistake.. but actually that is not causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line,

```
cursor.callproc('SearchStore', _query)
```

you must pass the argument as list.
Like this,

```
cursor.callproc('SearchStore', [_query,])
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the values argument must be a sequence, so a tuple - `(_query,)` would also work.  This error is usually caused by a string being passed; a string is also a sequence, so it is split into its constituent characters rather than being treated as a single object.